# update_create is creating new feilds instead of updating total

Tags: django, django-models

```
payments = list((expense
                     .annotate(month=Month('startDate'))
                     .values('month')
                     .annotate(total=Sum('cost'))
                     .order_by('month')))
    
    for i in payments:
        paymentMonths = (i["month"])
        paymentTotal= (i["total"])
        
        obj, created = Payment.objects.update_or_create(
            author=curruser,
            date=paymentMonths,
            total = paymentTotal,
            defaults={"total": paymentTotal},
            )
    totalcost = Payment.objects.filter(author = curruser.id)
```

[image]

Apparently, it should update the (date = 12) total but it is making new ones with the updated value, it might be because the totaldate is diff or maybe I'm wrong it is confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you just need to omit `total = paymentTotal` from your arguments.

```py
obj, created = Payment.objects.update_or_create(
    author=curruser,
    date=paymentMonths,
    defaults={"total": paymentTotal},
    )
```

This is because it is querying the DB to see if a Payment *with that total* already exists, and if it doesn't, it's creating a new one.  Instead, you want to query Payments with *curruser* as the `author` and with *date* as `paymentMonths`, while only updating *total* with the new `paymentTotal`

Comment: i did that but i got an error saying  "get() returned more than one Payment -- it returned 2!"

Comment: Do you have multiple Payments that are authored by the same user, as well as have the same date?  If so, you need to delete all but one (so that the query only returns one result)

Comment: omg im so dumb, i was looking all over the place  but i forgot to reset the database , lol ty so much.